# Use of à in different contexts

Tags: grammaire

According to some sources, à is a preposition which means many things:

to (je vais à la banque)

at (je travaille à deux kilomètres de la maison)

from ( j'habite à dix kilomètres de lui )

like ( je cuisine à la française )
many other meanings.

I have the following doubts:

1)In the second sentence, is it wrong to say, "J'habite de dix kilomètres de lui."

2) Also, I know à + le = au. But my textbook says: Mettez les phrases *au* pluriel... Why not "Mettez les phrases à (or even 'en') pluriel"  (What is the need for the definite article 'le'?)

3) 'à' is also used before (full) verbs for example, "Je vous invite à fêter le Diwali avec moi." But why is it not used before 'prendre' here: "Je préfère prendre du pain"

4) What is the need for 'à' after the verb 'joue'. "Je joue au tennis". Is the verb 'joue' an exception?

Comment: Prepositions may be the most unreliable class of words when it comes to 1:1 equivalent translations... which is interesting as a comment on how different languages model space and time.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, it's wrong. You can't say *j'habite de dix kilomètres...*

2) Unlike English, French requires an article before most nouns.

3) There is no simple rule, some combinations require *à*, some others *de* and others don't use any. See for example [that page](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/les-verbes-avec-la-preposition-de-ou-a-ou-sans-preposition-suivis-d-un-infinitif-88.php)

4) See 3)

Comment: Why is "j'habite de dix kilomètres" wrong?

Comment: Because that doesn't make sense just like you won't say I'm living from ten kilometers or I'm living out of ten kilometers

Comment: Oh... yes you're right.. I think what I really meant to ask was this: What is the need for "à" in that sentence.. Its translation is : I live 10 kilometres from him" (No translation for "à")

Comment: Yes, that need to be *j'habite à dix kilomètre de chez lui* but sometimes the preposition is optional, e.g. *j'habite [dans] une grande maison*, *j'habite [à] Paris*...